# MySQL error(0x80004005) when consuming a .net web service deployed on Azure

Tags: c#, mysql, web-services, azure

We have created a web service with the .net framework ".asmx", and inside the web method we have some MySQL block that writs some data to the remotly connected DB.
our database is Bitnami MySQL deployed on Microsoft Azure, when we run the .asmx page localy it runs without errors, but when we run it on Azure sometimes it works and most of times it returns this error:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()...
```

We use the latest MySQL .net connector and this is our connection string:

```
string MyConString = "user id=root;persistsecurityinfo=True;server=52.xxx.xx.xx;database=xxxxxxx;password='xxxxx';" ;
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO .........;";
connection.Open();
command.ExecuteReader();
connection.Close();
```

In the time I write this the service runs well and return success but then it fails again, so what seems to be the problem? thank you in advance.

Comment: ``our database is Bitnami MySQL deployed on Microsoft Azure, when we run the .asmx page localy it runs without errors`` Do you mean that Bitnami MySQL on Azure VM and the web service hosting on your local development machine works fine?

Comment: @FredHan-MSFT Yes the web service is working fine  in my local machine we can write to the remote DB, but when we deploy it on azure it works 3 times over 20 or so.